# Python Flask body as dataclass

Tags: python, flask

we are building REST service with python Flask, and as it is usually in large projects, our controller methods getting longer and longer, that make really hard to track, which parameters are used / expected from a POST request's body.

So I'm looking such a solution, where I could declare the controller method

```
@dataclass
class MyPOSTBodyDataClass:
   ...

@mod_formula_bp.route('/add/<id>', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def add(id, post_body: MyPOSTBodyDataClass):
    ...
```

So in that case I don't call `request.json["property_x"]` or similar.

Is it possible to implement in Flask?

***Note*** I have heard about the parameter validator, but I think, I'm looking to a slightly different solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Flask-Pydantic` to validate by MyPOSTBodyDataClass. More info: https://github.com/bauerji/flask-pydantic